# How do I make a ListBox activeX (basically a drop checklist) to show hidden rows

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I have created a List box with a total of 4 items. You can select multiple items in this sheet and I will like to make it so that each selection would show hidden rows, while being able to make multiple selections.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False
    Union(Rows("20:30"), Rows("51:56")).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("ListBox1"), Range(target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case target.Value
            Case "Asset Transfer"
                Rows("20:22").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Case "Fund Lineup"
                Rows("27:30").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Case "Plan Merge"
                Rows("23:26").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Case "Loans"
                Rows("51:56").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End Select
    End If
    Set target = Range("bulk")

    If target.Value = "Yes" Then
        Range("C60") = InputBox("Please enter the number of labor hours'")
        Range("D60") = InputBox("Enter Percentage Increase'")
    End If
        Set target = Range("AutoEnrollment")

    If target.Value = "Yes" Then
        Range("C59") = InputBox("Please enter the number of employees'")
    End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Basically I had it working for a data validation list perfectly and my range was an actual cell and what is said. But, now that I am trying to have multiple selections the list box does not really have a range in a cell that i know how to change. The problem I have right now is that even tho my excel sheet has things in the list box, I don't know how to have that list in the code also

Comment: How is your listbox being populated?

Comment: I created my list box by going into the developer tab, controls, insert, and then selected list box. I open its properties and I populated it by filling List fill range. I also enabled multiSelect to 1 and list style too